# How does region proposal network (RPN) and R-CNN works?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, object-recognition

I would like to know where I could find useful articles/papers about the basic concepts of *RPN* and *R-CNN*.

Answer (score 1):

There are many articles and papers that cover the basic concepts of **RPN and R-CNN**. Here are a few sources that you may find useful:

- The **original RPN and R-CNN** papers by Girshick et al. provide a detailed description of the algorithms and their performance on various object detection tasks:

  - Girshick, R., Donahue, J., Darrell, T., & Malik, J. (2014). Rich feature hierarchies for accurate object detection and semantic segmentation. In Proceedings of the IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (pp. 580-587).
  - Girshick, R., Iandola, F., Darrell, T., & Malik, J. (2015). Fast R-CNN. In Proceedings of the IEEE International Conference on Computer Vision (pp. 1440-1448).
- The [**official TensorFlow Object Detection API tutorial**](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) provides a high-level overview of RPN and R-CNN, along with code examples and implementation details.
- The blog post [**Object detection with R-CNN**](https://kaiminghe.com/publications/cvpr14rcnn.pdf) by Kaiming He provides a brief but informative introduction to R-CNN and its applications in object detection:
- The paper [**R-CNN, Fast R-CNN, and Faster R-CNN Explained**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.07264) by Yuxin Wu provides a comprehensive review of the RPN and R-CNN algorithms, including their evolution and performance on various benchmarks.
- A [**blog post by Adrian Rosebrock**](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/27/how-to-implement-a-region-proposal-network-rpn-in-keras/) that provides a high-level overview of RPN and R-CNN.

In general, RPN and R-CNN are used in object detection systems to generate high-quality region proposals and then classify those proposals using a convolutional neural network. RPN uses a sliding window approach to generate region proposals, while R-CNN uses a region proposal network to generate proposals and then applies a convolutional neural network to classify them. Both approaches have been shown to be effective for object detection tasks.

These resources should provide a good starting point for understanding the basic concepts of RPN and R-CNN.